# Spring: Qualifying different types with the same name

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired, qualifiers

I have two classes that I want to autowire using spring

```
@Component
public class Restaurant {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("HighClass")
    private CoffeeMaker coffeeMaker;
}
```

and:

```
public class CappuccinoMaker implements CoffeeMaker{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("HighClass")
    int numOfSpoons;
}
```

Then injecting:

```
@Bean(name="HighClass")
@Scope("prototype")
public CoffeeMaker HighClassCoffeeMakerGenerator() {
    return new CappuccinoMaker();
}
@Bean(name="HighClass")
public int getNumOfSpoons() {
    return 3;
}
```

I'd like to qualify both the int and the CoffeeMaker with "HighClass". In Guice it is possible to annotate different types with the same annotation and inject them correctly.

It seems like in spring this is not allowed. When I try injecting the fields I get an error that the required bean was not found. Did I miss anything?

Comment: In spring bean name is unique (see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-beanname). You could reach your goal using a @Profile https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bean name in Spring is [unique](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-beanname). Use [@Profile](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) in order to pick a bean from several competing variants.